# A proposition about an exact sequence of commutative groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

I'm trying to understand this fact, but I have problem with a part of the proof.

Let $0 \to A \to E \to B \to 0$ be an exact sequence of commutative groups (denoted additively) with $A$ and $B$ finite of orders $a$ and $b$ prime to each
other. Let $B':= \{x \in E|bx = 0\}$. Then $E$ is the direct sum of $A$ and $B'$.

The proof begins proving that $A \cap B'=\{0\}$.
Then, for every $x \in E$, I can write $x=(ar+bs)x$ with $r,s \in \mathbb{Z}$ using Bézout. Now the book says that, since $bB'=\{0\}$, $bE \subseteq A$, but I don't understand why. Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: What is $b$ in $B^{\prime}$?

Comment: The order? Or a multiple of it, because it annihilates every element of $B'$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to see that $bE\subseteq A$ is to note that $bE\subseteq\ker(E\ \rightarrow\ B)$ because $b=|B|$ annihilates $B$. Because the sequence is exact we get $bE\subseteq\ker(E\ \rightarrow\ B)=\operatorname{im}(A\ \rightarrow\ E)$, i.e. $bE\subseteq A$.

How this relates to the fact that $bB'=\{0\}$ I do not see at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have thought about using exactness of sequence, instead of the fact that $bB'=\{0\}$, because as you said, I can't see the connection. So you said: if $g$ is the map from $E$ to $B$, then for every $x=by \in bE$ $g(x)=bg(y)=0$ because $y \in E$ and $g(y) \in B$, right?

Comment: Now, if $f$ is the map from $A$ to $E$, $ker(g)=im(f)$, and $bE \subseteq ker(g)$. But how can I say that $im(f)=A$?

Comment: Indeed $bg(y)=0$ because $g(y)\in B$ and $bB=0$ because $b=|B|$. Because the sequence is exact $\ker(A\ \rightarrow\ E)=\operatorname{im}(0\ \rightarrow\ A)=0$, so $A\ \rightarrow\ E$ is injective meaning that $\operatorname{im}(A\ \rightarrow\ E)\cong A$ by the isomorphism theorem.

Comment: In general, in a short exact sequence 
$$0\ \longrightarrow\ X\ \longrightarrow\ Y\ \longrightarrow\ Z\ \longrightarrow\ 0,$$
the first and last arrows mean nothing more and nothing less than that $X\ \longrightarrow\ Y$ is injective and that $Y\ \longrightarrow\ Z$ is surjective.

Comment: Thanks, now is clear! But does it suffice to say that $bE \subseteq im(f)$ with $im(f)$ isomorphic to $A$ ?

Comment: Yes; in your question (and most likely in your book) the notation already suggests that $A$ is identified with its image in $E$; formally the intersection $A\cap B'$ makes no sense, in stead it should be the intersection $\operatorname{im}(f)\cap B'$. But as is often done with injective functions, the domain $A$ of the injective function $f$ is identified with its image $\operatorname{im}(f)$ in $E$.